# Maven PlugIn Dependency Exception

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a generic question that I know that it was not solvable until a point, based on the search results I could find on the web.

That refers to excluding dependencies that are downloaded by the plugins defined in a pom.xml file.

I provide below my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>SemanticFramework</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SemanticFramework Jersey Webapp</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>SemanticFramework</finalName>
        <plugins>

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.2</version>
                </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>


            </plugin>
            <!-- Run the application using "mvn embedded-glassfish:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                    <app>C:/Users/mariarousi/eclipse-workspace/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>




                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                         
                       


                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>



    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.20</version>
        </dependency>


         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openlink.virtuoso</groupId>
            <artifactId>virtjdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/virtjdbc4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>


            <groupId>com.openlink.virtuoso</groupId>
            <artifactId>virt_jena3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/virt_jena3.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-alpha.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.19</jersey.version>
        <glassfish.version>3.1.1</glassfish.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

the idea is that I want to exclude the depndencies that are imported by the plugins defined in the aforementioned pom file cause they provide some vulnerabilities. More specifically, I would like to exclude the `jsoup 1.10.2` which is automatically imported by one of the plugins that I use (not sure exactly which one, but I guess org.apache.maven.plugins).

As I know until a point this operation was not possible check also here (https://www.baeldung.com/mvn-plugin-dependency-exclusion), but due to me not being a pure java developer I am not sure if I missed something that allows such a functionality.

I would like also to mention that the java used is jdk-11 (before the fire starts I know I know that is ultra old version of java, but the application was built initially on it, and the client does not want changes in that regard).

So any ideas would be more than welcome.

Also, apologies if the question is not quite formalized in the manuals of the stack overflow community, but I am also a non-writer in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest on a quick & simple solution, sort of "quick and dirty" one.
Just import, directly in your pom, the `jsoup` dependency with a higher version, which is clean of vulnerabilities, and this will be taken into your final jar and override the transitive `jsoup 1.10.2` that is imported from the plugin.

Maven uses the "closest" to the root dependency that is found in the pom, if there are any conflicts.
Which means that if you have two different `jsoup` dependencies which imported to your project, one directly from your pom and the other in a transitive way, the first will be taken into your final jar.

You can read about it and maybe also specifically add tags like `<provided>` to indicate you'll provide the version and the dependency.

An important note: Do check if the plugin is compatible and works with the other version of `jsoup`. Make sure it works with the new version you are importing instead of the one it tries to import.

Also, make sure you use the newest version of any plugin, because these plugins are quite popular and most of them fix the vulnerabilities in each release, so instead of playing with the transitive dependencies, just update & upgrade the version of the plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. Thats is exactly how I am tackling it right now. I mean I import newer verions of the jar that have vulnerability issues. 

But I did not include that in the pom.xml that you are looking at cause I did not want to make the question even harder. 

Your verification that I am on the correct path, means a lot.

Thanks again for your feedback, it means a lot. Hope you have a good day :)

Comment: @alexandrosvassiliades no problem, and feel free to open more questions, as long as they are detailed and you've done some research by your own before :)